# Abstract the delete link for a polymorphic model used in a nested controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, polymorphic-associations

**Question**

In a polymorphic model, thats used in nested controllers, how can I abstract my delete link's path so I'm not hardcoding `upload_permitted_user_path(@permissible, permitted_user)`?

**Details**

I have a polymorphic model called `permitted users`. Basically theres a bunch of objects in my application where we need to control who can see it. So a `post`, `photo`, etc can have `permitted users`.

I want to be able to delete permitted users on the post#edit, photo#edit, etc pages.

I have this line:

```
# Used in "posts#edit"
<%= link_to 'Delete', 
  post_permitted_user_path(@permissible, permitted_user), # This should not be hardcoded.
  method: :delete, 
  data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %>

# Used in "photos#edit"
<%= link_to 'Delete', 
  photo_permitted_user_path(@permissible, permitted_user), # This should not be hardcoded.
  method: :delete, 
  data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %>
```

How can I abstract the path so I'm not hardcoding `<MY_TOP_LEVEL_CLASS>_permitted_user_path(@permissible, permitted_user)`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer (feel free to repost and I'll accept :P)

Creating polymorphic links is easy using "[polymorphic routes](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionDispatch/Routing/PolymorphicRoutes.html)".

You can easily generate the proper link using `polymorphic_url([@top_resource, @next_level_resource])` in any view.

For example:

`polymorphic_url([:admin, @article, @comment])` becomes `admin_article_comment_url(@article, @comment)`.

Another example without the leading `:admin`:

`polymorphic_url([@article, @comment])` becomes `article_comment_url(@article, @comment)`.